# Sort ObservableCollection<T> by type

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection and I add to this collection items of class Type1 and class Type2, both of these inherit from BaseClass.
Now in my collection Type1 items are the first ones. I want to sort the collection so that Type2 objects are the first in the collection.
This collection is binded to a TreeView and I want to show Type2 items first.

I do not know what are my options here. What is the best way to sort collection?

Comment: can you share classes and what have you tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort ObservableCollection<string> through C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112922/sort-observablecollectionstring-through-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

This will do it for you - but note that it will iterate over `items` twice.  If it's the result of an iterator block (i.e., 'lazy' execution) it will execute it twice.

```
void AddItemsByType(IEnumerable<BaseClass> items)
{
    return new ObservableCollection<BaseClass>(
        items.OfType<SubClassOne>().Concat(
             items.OfType<SubClassTwo>()
        )
    );
}
```

If it's important that you don't iterate over `items` twice, then you could do this:

```
void AddItemsByType(IEnumerable<BaseClass> items)
{
    items = items.ToList();
    return new ObservableCollection<BaseClass>(
        items.OfType<SubClassOne>().Concat(
             items.OfType<SubClassTwo>()
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = new ObservableCollection<BaseClass>();
result.AddRange(obvCol.OfType<Type2>().ToList());
result.AddRange(obvCol.OfType<Type1>().ToList());
```

And this if you don't want to be lazy
[How to sort a collection based on type in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874853/how-to-sort-a-collection-based-on-type-in-linq)

> collection.OrderBy(i => i.GetType() == typeof(A) ? 0 : 1);